# Javascript onmouseover border color changing function deleting the border

Tags: javascript, border, onmouseover, onmouseout

I've made a function to change a border's color onmouseover but for some reason it deletes the border without changing the color, so I can't change the color back onmouseout.
Here it is:

```js
function borderChange(id, color) 
        {
            document.getElementById(id).style.border = color;
        }
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu1" onmouseover="borderChange(this.id, 'White');" onmouseout="borderChange(this.id, 'Black');"> Text </div>
```

Comment: there is no border at all in your code snippet

Comment: Oh sorry, it's in the menu class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `border` shorthand property, if you don't specify the width and style then they default to `0` and `none` … at which point it doesn't matter what the colour is.

Set the `border-color` property instead.

```js
function borderChange(id, color) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor = color;
}
```

```css
div { border: solid red 1px; }
body { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu1" onmouseover="borderChange(this.id, 'White');" onmouseout="borderChange(this.id, 'Black');"> Text </div>
```

---

Aside…

Passing the id of the element and then immediately getting the element by its ID is pointless. Just pass the element itself.

```js
function borderChange(element, color) {
  element.style.borderColor = color;
}
```

```css
div { border: solid red 1px; }
body { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu1" onmouseover="borderChange(this, 'White');" onmouseout="borderChange(this, 'Black');"> Text </div>
```

Likewise, using JavaScript for this is overcomplicated. You can just use CSS.

```css
div { border: solid red 1px; }
div:hover { border-color: white; }
body { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu1"> Text </div>
```

Comment: I'm a student and unfortunately our teacher teaches us HTML in her way.
For example we have to build our websites with tables and not dives, thanks for a perfect answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The border is deleted because your code is written to override the `border` style.

You should just alter the `border-color`, not the `border` style.

[More about `border`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

```js
function borderChange(id, color) 
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor = color;
}
```

```css
#menu1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu1" onmouseover="borderChange(this.id, 'White');" onmouseout="borderChange(this.id, 'Black');"> Text </div>
```

Comment: Setting the border color to white is not the best choice on wihte background, seems like it doesn't work but you can see in console that it actually does.

Comment: @TunçelMert is it my mistake that OP decides to use `white` and follow what is given by the OP?

Comment: Of course not @YongQuan! And I actually upvoted your answer. But you have to make sure the result is clear for even morons that only see a disappearing border :) OP can change the color later as he wishes.